WooCommerce webhook URL cannot be reached
I'm creating a webhook in Woocommerce, but I have this error:
Error: Delivery URL cannot be reached: A valid URL was not provided.

But when I test in Postman this URL it works well, I don't know why I'm getting this error, maybe the port?

Solution:
To solve the issue, I had to add this code to the functions.php file of my theme to add my port as a secure one.
add_filter( 'http_allowed_safe_ports', 'wpdocs_allowed_ports' );

function wpdocs_allowed_ports( $ports ) {
    $ports = array( 80, 443, 8080, 3000 );

    return $ports;
}

more info:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/http_allowed_safe_ports/

Yes, most likely the port, I would guess. Try and see if this workaround helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738847/1427878

Your error message means your request is failing in 'wp-includes/class-wp-http.php' at line 275.
if ( empty( $url ) || empty( $parsed_url['scheme'] ) ) {
        $response = new WP_Error( 'http_request_failed', __( 'A valid URL was not provided.' ) );
        /** This action is documented in wp-includes/class-wp-http.php */
        do_action( 'http_api_debug', $response, 'response', 'WpOrg\Requests\Requests', $parsed_args, $url );
        return $response;
    }

Can you use the http_api_debug hook to log information about why your call is failing
e.g.
function log_http_api_debug( $response, $type, $class, $args, $url ) {
        error_log( 'HTTP API URL: ' . print_r( $url, true ) );
        error_log( 'HTTP API request: ' . print_r( $args, true ) );
        error_log( 'HTTP API response: ' . print_r( $response, true ) );
}
add_action( 'http_api_debug', 'log_http_api_debug', 10, 5 );

This will print information to your sites error log
